# Python | UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0119' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, pynput

So I started to learn and code using python.
I told myself that it would be cool to learn to make a keylogger using python and pynput.
But I get this error message `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0119' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>` when I use a different language, could somebody help me fix it? Thanks.

```py
import pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0
keys = []

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count
    keys.append(key)
    count += 1
    print("{0} pressed".format(key))

    if count >= 10:
        count = 0
        write_file(keys)
        keys = []

def write_file(keys):
    with open("my_keystrokes.txt", "w") as f:
        for key in keys:
            f.write(str(key))


def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: You will need to specify the argument `encoding='utf-8'` with your `open` call.

Comment: Bruh, how does this work in txt file :D
Thanks, you saved my day!